# Как правильно забэкапить базу Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, резервное-копирование

Имею postgres  и потоковую репликацию Master-Slave. На данный момент бэкап делается просто через pg_dump. Подумал, что будет лучше снимать бэкапы со Slave утилитой pg_basebackup

Делаю на слейве

```
/usr/local/bin/pg_basebackup -U pgsql -D /backup/test/tmp -Ft -z -Xf
```

И получаю

> pg_basebackup: could not initiate base backup: ERROR:  WAL generated with full_page_writes=off was replayed since last restartpoint
>   HINT:  This means that the backup being taken on the standby is corrupt and should not be used. Enable full_page_writes and run CHECKPOINT on the master, and then try an online backup again.

Как я понял, нужно менять в конфиге на мастере параметр full_page_writes, но для этого еще и мастер нужно рестартовать.

Стоит ли бэкапить вообще базу через pg_basebackup или оставить pg_dump? Если я правильно понимаю, то через pg_dump мы теряем все новые транзакции, которые прилетели уже во время, когда делался дамп.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgbasebackup.html и https://habrahabr.ru/post/222311/

Comment: база данных большая?

Comment: База примерно 600 гигов

Answer (score 4):

`pg_dump` хорош при бэкапе "на холодную". Когда базу никто не трогает.

`pg_basebackup` - в этом плане лучше - создает "горячую" копию. Он осуществляет бэкап в несколько этапов: выполняет контрольную точку, копирует файловую систему в указанный каталог, копирует в каталог/pg_xlog все нужные сегменты WAL, конец копирования. Таким образом все транзакции, ", которые прилетели уже во время, когда делался дамп" попадут в бэкап.

Еще лучше непрерывная архивация (процесс archiver) - помимо бэкапа сохранять все последующие журналы WAL на отдельном сервере. Что позволит восстановить базу на произвольный момент времени. Также требует небольшой подстройки master.

Answer (score 0):

**pg_dump нужен для копирования отдельной базы**, схемы или набора таблиц. Можно бэкапить в 3-х форматах: plain sql, gzipped и directory. Бэкапы такого рода полезны при переносе между серверами, ведения отдельной истории по каждой базе/схемы.

**pg_base_backup нужен для** быстрого разворачивания реплик, **восстановления к точке во времени** (Point in Time Recovery).

**Бэкап с помощью pg_base_backup делается только с мастера**. Это связано с несколькими факторами. Подробнее на сайте [postgresql pro](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/app-pgbasebackup.html)

> Стоит ли бэкапить вообще базу через pg_basebackup или оставить pg_dump? Если я правильно понимаю, то через pg_dump мы теряем все новые транзакции, которые прилетели уже во время, когда делался дамп.

**Бэкап каждой базы нужно делать всегда**. pg_base_backup делается в совокупности с pg_dump. Отдельно он не полезен ввиду своего размера.

Если в pg_dump не устраивает производительность стоит воспользоваться форматом directory. **Директорией можно дампить базу в нескольких потоках**. В моем случае база размеров в **100 GB бэкапится за 30 минут**